# Rendering Java graphics in full screen

Tags: java, graphics

I was wonder if there was a way to scale a graphics object with the size of a JFrame. So that if i make my JFrame fullscreen, all of the graphics will scale based on the size that i set for them. Thanks

Comment: Are talking about Graphics2D.scale?

Comment: I have no idea. I am still learning java. Like i if i am drawing a rectangle the the screen and i want to make my screen full screen. how do i scale that rectangle up so that it does not look super small.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public void paint (Graphics g) { //could also be paintComponent(Graphics g)
  Dimension initS = initialScale;
  Dimension currS = getSize();
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.scale(((Double)currS.width)/initS.width, ((Double)currS.Height)/initS.height);
  //do your painting
}
```

Comment: this got my graphics to scale but now all my game logic is messed up. How do i scale numbers with this?

Comment: same way. x scale = ((Double)currS.width)/initS.width, y scale = ((Double)currS.Height)/initS.height

Comment: i guess i'm just confused. In my program i am creating a game. I created my own buttons. The problem is that when i scale the image, the bounds do not get scaled up either